# Function whose gradient is of constant norm

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, gradient-flows

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a smooth function such that $\|\nabla f(x)\|=1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $f(0)=0$.

I would like to prove that $f$ is linear.

I first looked at the solution of the O.D.E. $$\dfrac{d\gamma}{dt}(t)=\nabla f(\gamma(t))$$
I noticed that there exists only one solution $\gamma_x$ passing through $x\in \mathbb R^n$ at $t=0$, and such a solution is defined over $\mathbb R$. I also proved that $$\gamma_x(t)=x+t\nabla f(x)$$ and $$f(\gamma_x(t))=f(x)+t.$$

Furthermore, the following hint is given :

> Show that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $\langle \nabla f(x),x-y\rangle=\langle \nabla f(y),x-y\rangle=0$.

I did it, but now, I don't understand why it follows that $f$ is linear.

**Edit**: I write here the proof of the hint;

Let $c:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be the (usual) parametrization of the segment $[x+t\nabla f(x),y]$. Since $f(x)=f(y)$, we get $$\begin{align*}|t|=|f(\gamma_x(t))-f(x)| & =|f(x+t\nabla f(x))-f(y)|\\ & =|\int_0^1 \langle \nabla f(c(s)),c'(s)\rangle ds| \\ & \leq \int_0^1 \|c'(s)\|ds \\ & =\|y-x-t\nabla f(x)\|\end{align*}$$
From this inequality, which is true for any $t\in \mathbb R$ and using the fact that $\nabla f(x)$ is a unitary vector, it follows that :
$$t^2\leq \|x-y\|^2 + t^2 +2t\langle x-y,\nabla f(x) \rangle$$
Dividing by $t$ and taking limits to $\pm \infty$ gives the hint.

Comment: How did you prove the hint?

Comment: @JackLee: I've just edited my question to write the proof of the hint.

Comment: OK. There's a small problem with your proof of the hint: when you introduce the integral, you shouldn't use $t$ for the variable of integration along the path $c$, because that's already being used to designate the point $x+t\nabla f(x)$, which is one of the endpoints of $c$.  But other than that, I think this argument works. As I mentioned in my comment to @John below, proving the hint requires some global argument, and taking the limit as $t\to\pm\infty$ is it. With this, I think something along the lines that John suggested will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your tags, I suppose I can use some geometric argument here.

Because of the condition $\|\nabla f\| = 1$, the level set

$$M = M_c = \{x\in \mathbb R^n: f(x) = c\}$$

is a smooth hypersurface for all $c\in \mathbb R$ and for all $x\in M$,

$$T_xM = \{ y + x \in \mathbb R^n : \langle y, \nabla f (x) \rangle = 0\}.$$

Let $x\in M$ and $y \in M$ be closed to $x$. The condition

$$\langle \nabla f(x), x-y \rangle = 0$$

says that $x-y$ lie in the tangent space of $T_x M$ for all $y\in M$. Then $y\in T_xM$ for all $y$ closed to $x$ (Some arguments are needed here). With some more argument, one can show that $M = T_xM$ for all $x\in M$. This mean that

- For all $c$, $M_c = V + cw$, where $w\in \mathbb R^n$ is a vector with norm one and $V = \{ x: \langle x, w\rangle = 0\}$,
- $f(u+ tw) = g(t)$, where $u\in V$ and $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $g'(t)=1$ for all $t$.

The second claim show that $f$ is linear.

Comment: I don't think this works. You seem to be claiming that $\left<\nabla f(x),x-y\right>=0$ for all $y\in M$ close to $x$ (I assume that's what you mean by "closed to $x$").  But this can't be shown to be true by a local argument. For example, on $\mathbb R^2$, the function $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ has unit gradient everywhere it's differentiable, but it's not linear. You'll need to use some global argument based on the fact that $f$ is smooth everywhere on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @JackLee: Actually I am just using his hint there. I haven't shown that it is true. I guess the global argument (which must be needed as you mentioned) has been used in some of the claims by the OP.

Comment: OK.  The OP has now posted his proof of the hint, and it does indeed include a global argument (taking a limit as $t\to\pm\infty$). So with that, I think something along the lines of your argument will work.

Comment: @John: Ok, but if $\langle x-y,\nabla f(x)\rangle=0$ then $y=x+(y-x)$ always lies in $T_xM$, no matter if $y$ is closed or not to $x$, right ? So the key point now is to prove that $M=T_xM$, could you explain a bit your arguments ?

Comment: @Bebop: Yes. The main point is to show $M = T_xM$. You can also argue that as $M\subset T_xM$ and $M$ is closed hypersurface, then $M= T_xM$.

Comment: I am not sure this is obvious, is it ? Don't we need an other argument as the convexity of $M$ to ensure the equality ?

Comment: @Bebop: From $\langle \nabla f(x), x-y\rangle = 0$ we have that $M \subset T_xM$. But $M$ is closed and has the same dimension as $T_xM$, so is open. Thus $M = T_xM$. The "closedness" of $y$ to $x$ as mentioned in the answer seem to be unnecessary now.

Comment: Ok, so, correct me if I'm wrong about the fact that $M$ is open in $T_xM$: $M$ turns out to be a submanifold of $T_xM$ and any submanifold of top dimension is an open set of the ambient space. Which means that $M$ is actually open in $T_xM$ ?

Comment: @Bebop: You are right.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help, now everything is clear to me.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is a very old question, but the claim is not true. Take $f(x) = \|x\|$, which has gradient $\nabla f(x) = x/\|x\|$. Obviously, $\|\nabla f(x)\|=1$, but the function does not satisfy the properties of a linear function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This function is not smooth, though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1923317)